# How to lock and hide the cursor in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

It's a simple question, but how do I lock the cursor and hide the cursor in my Unity games?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Unity 5.2, you should use the [`Cursor` class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor.html).

> **Static Variables**
>
> `lockState` How should the cursor be handled?
>
> `visible` Should the cursor be visible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
void Start ()
{
    Screen.showCursor = false;
}
```

ie, try to add `Screen.showCursor = false` inside the Start function. This will hide the cursor from the entire game.

Also refer: [Screen.lockCursor](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-lockCursor.html)

Comment: It is deprecated since 5.x and removed in `2017`

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use this:

```
void Start()
{
    Cursor.visible = true;
}
```

Because Screen.ShowCursor is deprecated.